# if statement not working properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have two arrays: `arr` and `myArraycode`. Both have some values retrieved from a database. The values of `myArraycode` are displayed in `select` on each row. Now I need to disable all rows which have a value not appearing in the `arr` array.

For example,

```
arr =["abc","cde"];
myArraycode=["sample","abc","cde"];
```

I have three table rows which have `sample` in one row, `abc` in another and `cde` in a third. Now i need to disable the row with `sample` because `sample` is not in the array `arr`.

I have tried the following code:

```
var kt = 0;
var kts = 0;

var sk=0;
var sv =0;


while(kt < myArraycode.length)
{ 
    if($.inArray(myArraycode[kt],arr) === -1 )
    {

        $("#table tr").find('td').find("select:contains("+myArraycode[kt]+")").closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').attr("disabled","disabled");;

        $("#table tr").find('td').find("select:contains("+myArraycode[kt]+")").closest('tr').find('select').attr("disabled","disabled");;               
    }
    kt++;
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98L26/)

Comment: first there is a syntax error in `arr ={"abc","cde"};` it should be `arr =["abc","cde"];`

Comment: i was showing you sample values .It has values inserted using array.push("value")

Comment: use .prop() to set the disabled state

Comment: you have a recursive loop since the value of `kt` is not incremented

Comment: sorry Arun i just missed it out while posting.please check my edited question

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle example and for the record `arr ={"abc","cde"};` is not an array...

Comment: i have created jsfiddle.please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code to disable select box having selected value as sample

```
$( document ).ready(function(e){


arr =["abc","cde"];
myArraycode=["sample","abc","cde"];

for(var i=0; i < myArraycode.length; i++)
{ 
   if($.inArray(myArraycode[i],arr) === -1 )
   {
$("select").each(function(){

    if($(this).val() == myArraycode[i])
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('select').attr('disabled','disabled');

    }
});    


 }
}

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98L26/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr =["abc","cde"];
myArraycode=["sample","abc","cde"];

for(var i=0; i < myArraycode.length; i++)
{ 
   if($.inArray(myArraycode[i],arr) === -1 )
   {
   $('option[selected="selected"]:contains("'+myArraycode[i]+'")').parent().attr('disabled','disabled');       
 }
}
```

I've corrected some of the syntax errors, but this should do the trick for you
For performance reasons you could also either use a decremental for loop or save the array.length value in a variable so the loop doesn't need to recalculate the value every run

I have updated your answer in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98L26/7/)

Note that the HTML requires the selected attribute for this to work

```
<option value="sample" selected="selected">sample</option>
```

Comment: Thanks Ayame.But when i tried it is not disabling any rows

Comment: from the question , @krishna is trying to disable the `select` element.

Comment: my apologies, I missed the select bit!

Comment: @anurupr you was right, i am trying to disable `select` and `input box`

Comment: i have created jsfiddle.please check it out

Comment: @Ayame__ your code disables all select fields.please check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/98L26/1/

Comment: I always thought it was a good idea to assign length to a variable in js because then it is not recalculated on every iteration. This is true of some languages but length property is a stored value in javascript. Does seem like there is a very small saving by caching value but unsure why it is and only really is apparent after a million iterations

Comment: Answer updated, but because you find sample in all the selectboxes, all of them get disabled. If you remove sample from the others you will see the difference

Comment: @JonDay True, the optimisation is minimal, however often appraised as best practice, hence my mentioning but no appliance

Comment: It is best practice yes. Its just interesting that there is a performance hit at all given that length is already stored as object property and not recalculated per iteration

Comment: but is there a way to disable only `select` having selected value as sample

Comment: Thanks a lot Ayame. May be your answer didnt solve my problem. But your comment `but because you find sample in all the selectboxes, all of them get disabled.` made me think what i missed out and saved my day. +1 for that comment and your support.

Comment: The easiest way to only select the selectbox which has sample selected is to make sure that to the html it is selected by adding the selected="selected" attribute to it. I have updated the example on jsfiddle and in the answer

Comment: Thanks. your solution was more simple than the one i used.

Comment: unfortunately i have more no of select tags in real code and adding select attribute to them is really hard.so i will remember your solution and i will accept my answer